# How to get to JDialog methods?

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I just get stuck with app. The thing is in second actionListener, I want to get object or more specifically access to methods in my JDialog class.

I got few dialogs created, but not visible. In first actionListener I get to them by getDialog function which is returning JDialog. So I can each one of them visible. 
2nd actionListener which I need help with, is showing JOptionPane and if user pick the YES_OPTION I want to run my method from specific dialog.

I it's not clear I'd try to fix my explanations so you can understand it.

```
modifyButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JButton thisButton = (JButton) e.getSource();
            JPanel parentPanel = (JPanel) thisButton.getParent();
            Container topLevel = parentPanel.getTopLevelAncestor();
            MainFrame mainFrame = (MainFrame) topLevel;

            mainFrame.getDialog(TABLECOUNTER).setVisible(true);

        }
    });

    abortButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Object[] options = {"Tak", "Nie"};
            int userReply = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Czy na pewno chcesz anulować rachunek?", "Probujesz anulować rachunek!", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);
            if (userReply == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                JButton thisButton = (JButton) e.getSource();
                JPanel parentPanel = (JPanel) thisButton.getParent();
                Container topLevel = parentPanel.getTopLevelAncestor();
                MainFrame mainFrame = (MainFrame) topLevel;

                mainFrame.getDialog(TABLECOUNTER).myMethod(); //here
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to better help up understand what's going on

Comment: Does `getDialog` return a standard `JDialog`? Show the method.

Comment: Are you getting an error trying to access the method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "I want to get object or more specifically access to methods in my JDialog class"

If the method `getDialog` returns a standard `JDialog`,

```
public JDialog getDialog(...) {}
```

Then you're stuck with the methods of `JDialog`, without proper casting, or changing the return type. That would explain why you are able to `setVisible` in the first method, because `JDialog` does have a method `setVisible`. So to access the method `myMethod` you'll want to do some casting.

```
((MyDialog)mainFrame.getDialog(TABLECOUNTER)).myMethod();
```

---